# Displaying Image using Cassandra Database blob data

Tags: html, node.js, cassandra

I am storing an image to cassandra db (blob data) and I am trying to get the data and display in my html page,but it is displaying some garbage data.

I am using cassandra as a database,node js as a backend server and cassandara-client for handling cassandra database.

complete description-

I am able to store image to cassandra database.

I am also getting image data from cassandra database,but I don't know in which format the data is?(base64,binary...etc).

I am also able to write the data into a image file using the below code-

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile("file1.png", new Buffer(imgData, "base64"), function(err) {});
```

But I don't want to write data into file .I want to stream the data directly into a image in html.I have used the below code for displaying image in my html page-

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: 'http://10.0.0.1:3000/getMap', 
   type: 'GET', 
   headers: {
   "accept": "image/jpg",
            "content-Type": "image/jpg",
    },
   success: function(data) { 
    console.log("Inside success");
    $('#mapdiv').html('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'+data+'"  height="200px"  width="500px"/>');
    }
   }); 

<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

but i am getting some garbage data inside the div.

Thanks in advance
Subhra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your binary content will be stored as an array of bytes in Cassandra with big [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). In order for your HTML to work, you will need to convert that byte array into a base64-encoded string first.

One thing to watch out for though - depending on the architecture of your machine, you might need to convert the byte array back into little endian format first. That's usually a matter of just reversing the contents of the byte array if you are using little endian.

Comment: Thanks Aaron,it worked for me after converting the binary data to base 64 sting.I have used the below code for converting binary to base64-     base64data = new Buffer(imgData, 'binary').toString('base64');

Comment: Looks good! Also looks like, from the snippet you posted, that you don't need to worry about endianness.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra stores data as binary. So, if your write to file code works as expected, I am guessing the data variable in your JS code should really be the base64 encoded value of what you get from Cassandra.